# How to pass arguments with spaces to MinGW-MSYS shell scripts from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, escaping, sh

I have a sh script, `myscript.sh`, which takes a directory as an input argument and does some recursive processing of the files in that directory. I want to run this script in Windows command line (I use the [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)/MSYS distribution).

How do I properly provide a path with spaces as an input argument?

For example, I want to give a path, 'dirA\dir B'. I tried many different combinations, including

```
sh -c 'myscript.sh "dirA/dir B"'

sh -c 'myscript.sh "dirA/dir\ B"'

sh -c "myscript.sh 'dirA/dir\\ B'"

sh -c "myscript.sh \"dirA/dir B\" "

sh -c "myscript.sh dirA/dir\ B "
```

But on all of them the script understands the path as 'dirA/dir'.

Answer (score 0):

cmd doesn't understand single quotes. If sh does, then make the outer quotes double, so that you're double-quoting the argument at the cmd prompt, and passing the single quotes to sh to interpret.

The third option you listed is the right idea, but it's not clear to me what you're doing with the **\\**. Does sh require you to escape the space within a double-quoted string? If I'm not mistaken, it's either/or, not both. One of these should work (depending on whether your sh Windows port uses Unix-style forward slash path separators or Windows-style backslash separators or both):

```
sh -c "myscript.sh 'dirA/dir B'"
```

or

```
sh -c "myscript.sh 'dirA\dir B'"
```

I'm not sure why the fourth option doesn't work. That method works fine for passing double-quoted arguments to PowerShell from cmd. For example, this works:

```
powershell -noexit "sl \"C:\Program Files\""
```

This leads me to suspect that it's sh that's having a problem with the path arguments `'dirA/dir B'` and `"dirA/dir B"` -- especially if the suggestions above don't work.

Speaking of PowerShell, you might want to give that a try instead. Any of the following should work:

```
sh -c 'myscript.sh "dirA/dir B"'

sh -c "myscript.sh 'dirA/dir B'"

sh -c 'myscript.sh ''dirA/dir B'''

sh -c "myscript.sh `"dirA/dir B`""
```

Comment: Unfortunately, on all the variants you  suggested the result is the same. The only difference is that `sh -c "myscript.sh \"dirA/dir B\""` in Powershell (not in cmd) gives another error, saying that bash can't find matching double-quote in its input argument. Probably the problem is in sh/bash.

Comment: I didn't suggest trying that in PowerShell. That's only good for cmd and is guaranteed not to work in PowerShell. The only place where a backslash is ever an escape character in PowerShell is in regular expressions. Otherwise the escape character is the backtick, as shown in my fourth PowerShell option. Please try copying and pasting all four verbatim. If that doesn't work, that *would* indicate that the problem is in sh. Did you try the command you're passing directly at an sh prompt?

Comment: Also, how does bash ever get involved, if you're invoking sh from a Windows prompt and running an sh script? Is there something you're leaving out?

Comment: What are the contents of **myscript.sh**? I suspect that's where the problem lies - you're passing the argument correctly, from the Windows prompt to sh, and from sh to the script, but then the script doesn't handle it correctly. Do you have it double-quoted everywhere you use it in the script, i.e. `some_sh_command "$1"`? I believe something like `cd $path` doesn't work in sh if **$path** has spaces (unlike PowerShell, which implicitly quotes string arguments). You need `cd "$path"`.

Comment: @xivaxy So, did you try double-quoting the string in your sh script? Based on the information you've provided, I'm pretty sure that's where the answer lies.